# Jquery Validator not validating email ID created with random string with its email attribute

Tags: jquery, validation, email

This line of code does not work for email something like: akg@gol.red...???

```
$("#admin_forget").validate({rules: {email: {required: true, email: true}}});
```

So, I created a new method and it works:

```
$.validator.addMethod("validate_email", function (value, element) {
     if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4est(value)) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 }, "Please enter a valid email address.");
 $("#admin_login_form").validate({
     errorClass: "error-msg", rules: {
         email: {
             required: true,
           //email: true,
             validate_email:true
         }
     }
});
```

Is there any way to use a default method instead of adding a new one?

Answer (score 1):

I think it may help you.

You can modify your regex

/^([\w-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([\w-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$/

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100%, but I'm pretty sure the built in Validator does not accept ".red" as a domain. It specifially looks for the common ones. I've had issues with this before. Using your own regex is probably better anyway.